# If I apply the excel file to the html table, I want to give each td a different id

Tags: javascript

Sign up and first question. I keep looking to solve my problem but haven't found an answer yet. The question is, like the title, I want to load an excel file into an html table and give each td a different ID.

Currently, I have succeeded in assigning an id, but I know that the id value must not be the same. So I want to solve this problem with vanilla JavaScript. Below are the scripts I've completed so far and the results shown in the Chrome Developer Tools.

SCRIPT:

```
            document.getElementById("ex_file").onchange = (evt) => {

        var reader = new FileReader();
        

        reader.addEventListener("loadend", (evt) => {

            var table = document.getElementById("importexcel");
            table.innerHTML = "";
        

            var workbook = XLSX.read(evt.target.result, {type: "binary"}),
                worksheet = workbook.Sheets[workbook.SheetNames[0]],
                range = XLSX.utils.decode_range(worksheet["!ref"]);
        

            for (let row=range.s.r; row<=range.e.r; row++) {
            let r = table.insertRow();
            
            for (let col=range.s.c; col<=range.e.c; col++) {
                let c = r.insertCell(),
                xcell = worksheet[XLSX.utils.encode_cell({r:row, c:col})];
                c.innerHTML = xcell.v;
                
                c.setAttribute('id', 'excel' + numbering)
                var numbering = 0;
                numbering++;
                
            }
            }
        });
        

        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(evt.target.files[0]);
        };
```

Chrome Developer Tools:

```
<table id="importexcel" class="table">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td id="excelundefined">STYLE</td>
<td id="excel1">XS 90</td>
<td id="excel1">X 95</td>
<td id="excel1">M 100</td>
<td id="excel1">L 105</td>
<td id="excel1">XL 110</td>
<td id="excel1">XXL 115</td>
<td id="excel1">TOTAL</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id="excel1">hgfhgfhgf</td>
<td id="excel1">3</td>
<td id="excel1">4</td>
<td id="excel1">0</td>
<td id="excel1">4</td>
<td id="excel1">0</td>
<td id="excel1">4</td>
<td id="excel1">15</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Below is the result I want:

```
<table id="importexcel" class="table">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td id="excelundefined">STYLE</td>
<td id="excel1">XS 90</td>
<td id="excel2">X 95</td>
<td id="excel3">M 100</td>
<td id="excel4">L 105</td>
<td id="excel5">XL 110</td>
<td id="excel6">XXL 115</td>
<td id="excel7">TOTAL</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id="excel8">hgfhgfhgf</td>
<td id="excel9">3</td>
<td id="excel10">4</td>
<td id="excel11">0</td>
<td id="excel12">4</td>
<td id="excel13">0</td>
<td id="excel14">4</td>
<td id="excel15">15</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

The script used another developer's script. If there is a problem, I would like to get help. Please feel free to comment if you need a little more information for an accurate answer!

Comment: you are declaring `numbering` inside of the loop

Comment: Thanks to @Daniel A. White I solved it by adding var numbering to the starting point. But the first row is visible, but the second row is not. What's the problem?